# How can i use .cs files that generated by a .tt file, separately?

Tags: c#, file, project, t4

I used a `.tt` file in c# to generate some `.cs` files, how can I use these generated class separately in my project, without `.tt` file?

Comment: Generate the file one and copy it somewhere else? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Generate cs files in my project with a tt file, then remove tt file, and use only cs files.

Comment: Why is it a problem if the .tt file remains?

Comment: i change somethings manually in some generated files. so if .tt files run again it overwrite my changes.

Comment: That defeats the benefits of T4. If you need to modify the generated code rely on partial classes and methods.

Comment: some of my changes seems that could not apply on partial class, for example i want mark some properties of some class as [Nonserializable]

Comment: In that case extend the model so that the template can inject the correct attributes.

Comment: could you explain more, please?

Comment: Always prefer to modify the template rather than modifying the generated code.  Make the template read the data from some list of classes to mark as nonserializable and then generate what you need.  Store the list anywhere you like.  Just a list of class names in a flat file should be enough.

Comment: thanks, i think it's a good way for this case, i asked another question in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796145/customizing-some-auto-generated-codes-with-t4) also, could you please answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open your project file as xml, either by unloading and editing in VS or by opening in some external text editor, you can remove the .tt file manually. On the generated .cs files there will also be a DependentUpon tag referencing the .tt file that should be removed as well.