# customizing some auto generated codes with T4

Tags: c#, templates, customization, t4, auto-generate

I Used "EF 4.x DbContext Fluent Genarator" to generate my poco classes , mapping files and also Context file, in EF Code first.(in fact "EF 4.x DbContext Fluent Genarator" uses 3 T4 files)
now i want apply some changes on auto generated codes:

1. change namespace of some classes.
2. Mark some fields of some classes as [NonSerializable]
3. change body of Some auto generated custom methods on pocos that i added to T4 template.

how can i do these works with continuing using T4 files?

Answer (score 0):

for #3. this should help

These classes are partial classes so you can create a new .cs file with same class as partial.
add custom methods.

I can not think a straight forward way for #1. & #.2 becase
Changes to Auto generated classes will be lost when someone updates / build it again.

Comment: thanks, but for #3 how can i do it? for example if in my auto generated code i have `public string ToString();` that return a value, how can i change it with partial class, that return another value?

Comment: Say you have generated partial class Client -> ClientName is string property -> GetClientNumber() is method returns number.

Now in Solution -> under the same project of Generated Client.cs create a folder -> Extended Class -> in this create ClientExtend.cs but the class would be partial Client -> now Create your new custom method / property here -> e.g. new method could be GetClientNumberAsString() now client object will have both generated and custom method.

Comment: BTW alternatively - Extensions method can also help . e.g. Create Extension method for client that returns number as string.

Comment: No, i don't want to change name of my method, because for example in DataGridview ,`ToString()` method, is special. (if you bind a column of DGV to a navigation property, it call ToString() of navigation property object)

Comment: hmm interesting - i am out of ideas - do post when you get an answer. Happy Coding.

Comment: this is old post but curios to know what happened ? how it was solved ?